# Using Pandas find highest value for each unique group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to Pandas and I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
ID        HeatIndexCat       
1         Lower               
1         Moderate               
1         Moderate               
2         Lower               
2         High               
3         High      
3         Lower
```

I would like to assign values to each category (e.g. Lower=33, Moderate=33 to 93, High=39 to 46) and get the highest category from each group with similar ID.

This is the desired outcome:

```
ID        HeatIndexCat       Max
1         Lower              Moderate 
1         Moderate               
1         Moderate               
2         Lower              High 
2         High               
3         High               High
3         Lower
```

Comment: What does mean `Moderate=33 to 93, High=39 to 46` ?

Comment: Can you add expected output with new column filled by numbers?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include it. I am working on a heat index dataset. These values are in °C.

Comment: Erratum: Moderate=33 to 39. @jezrael, do you mean output the max with number values instead of the category?

Comment: No, you need `would like to assign values to each category (e.g. Lower=33, Moderate=33 to 93, High=39 to 46)` - can you add expected output with column filled these numbers?

Comment: Basically what @jezrael says is that Moderate 33-93 and High 39-46 intersect, "High" is basically a subset of "Moderate", how we know which one to assign ? Did you mean Moderate is 33-93 except the range of High ?

Comment: Oh. Thank you for pointing it out. I added a correction above that moderate is 33 to 39.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#create dict for values
d = {'Lower':33, 'Moderate':34, 'High': 40}

#create new column
df['new'] = df['HeatIndexCat'].map(d)

#get row maximal value of new per groups
df['Max'] = df.set_index('HeatIndexCat').groupby('ID')['new'].transform('idxmax').values
print (df)
   ID HeatIndexCat  new       Max
0   1        Lower   33  Moderate
1   1     Moderate   34  Moderate
2   1     Moderate   34  Moderate
3   2        Lower   33      High
4   2         High   40      High
5   3         High   40      High
6   3        Lower   33      High
```

If want only first values per groups:

```
df['Max'] = df['Max'].mask(df['ID'].duplicated(), '')
print (df)
   ID HeatIndexCat  new       Max
0   1        Lower   33  Moderate
1   1     Moderate   34          
2   1     Moderate   34          
3   2        Lower   33      High
4   2         High   40          
5   3         High   40      High
6   3        Lower   33
```